# java.io.FileNotFoundException uploading image with apache.commons

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I'm developing a Spring-MVC project that requires uploading images by the users of the app. I'm using apache.commons, Eclipse Mars2 and Java1.8. Everytime I test the upload, eclipse console throws this:

EDIT: it seems the problem is to find the path to the project independently of the OS. At this moment we are using:

```
File localFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.home")+File. separator+ "workspace"+File. separator+"ProyectoSpring"+File. separator + "WebContent" + File. separator+"usr"+File. separator+imagen.getNombreImagen());
```

The problem is the workspace is hardcoded and the app is being developed by more people. Any way to find the path to the project? user.dir returns the eclipe path, not the project or workspace.

Original question:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\UserName\workspace\ApacheTomcat7\ProyectoSpring\WebContent\usr\back.jpg (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at controller.ImagenController.grabarFicheroALocal(ImagenController.java:84)
at controller.ImagenController.processAddSubmit(ImagenController.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:440)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:428)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Controller methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadImagen" , method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public String addImagen(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("imagen", new Imagen());
    return "imagen/uploadImagen";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/uploadImagen", method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public String processAddSubmit(@ModelAttribute("imagen") Imagen imagen,
                                BindingResult bindingResult) { 
    //if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
    //      return "imagen/uploadImagen";
    //

    try {

        String aux = imagen.getFichero().getOriginalFilename();
        imagen.setImageName(System.getProperty("catalina.home")+ File. separator +"ProyectoSpring"+ File. separator +"WebContent"+ File. separator +"usr"+ File. separator + aux);
        grabarFicheroALocal(imagen);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "user/error";
    }        
     return "redirect:../index.jsp";
 }


private void grabarFicheroALocal(Imagen imagen) throws Exception {

    CommonsMultipartFile uploaded = imagen.getFichero();
    File localFile = new File(imagen.getImageName());
    FileOutputStream os = null;

    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(localFile);
        os.write(uploaded.getBytes());

    } finally {
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An extract from the object:

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;



public class Imagen {

    private String imageName;
    private CommonsMultipartFile fichero;


public Imagen(){
    super();
}   

//GETTERS AND SETTERS

public CommonsMultipartFile getFichero() {
    return fichero;
}

public void setFichero(CommonsMultipartFile fichero) {
    this.fichero = fichero;
}
...
```

Of course, the image is not uploaded. In other pc with Linux (I'm using W7-64) the code works, so I suspect it may be a permissions problem, but all folders in the path have write permissions. Any ideas? Thx.

Comment: Do all folders specified really exist on your system? Especially the on named "Apa**r**cheTomcat7"?

Comment: Yeah, the path is obtained using System.getProperty("catalina.home"). I know it's strange, but is a native function, don't know why is returning "apaRche".

Comment: Ok, the installation folder for apache had a missplaced name, but now is correct and the problem persists. Anyway thanks piet.t, I changed the error in the question.

Comment: Ok, the problem seems to be the System.getProperty("catalina.home"). In Linux works fine, but in W7 returns the path to the project. Using System.getProperty("user.dir") or Using System.getProperty("user.home") don't return the desired path.